# PyTorch enforce non-negative values in convolution weigths inside the model

Tags: python, pytorch

As we know, the optimization parameters used in ML are not constrained, and thus you can't really enforce parameters to be positive. In scientific articles, whenever this is needed, I see it implemented as (pseudocode):

```
optimizer.step()
model.weights=max(model.weights ,0)
```

Which works. However, I was wondering if there is a way to put this constraint inside the model?
Say, given a complex model where only some weights are required to be positive, is there a way to make an update on these apply this constraint, so its part of the model, rather than part of the training? e.g. by overloading however the weights are updated?

This makes sense conceptually in some models, as some model definitions require some weights  to have this constraint, and I would like whoever uses the model to not need to remember to apply this at training, but the model to be defined as such.

Or the only way to do so is by doing it as described above?

Comment: interesting example here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496283/how-to-force-logistic-regression-weights-to-be-always-positive-in-pytorch-equi for a fully connected layer, maybe something you want to generalize to a convolutional one

Comment: @Learningisamess right, but I'm not entirely sure that answer generalises well to conv layers... Plus doing an abs() is a terrible idea anyway (Albeit easy to change)